# Is this design in 5NF?

Tags: relational-database

A user can have only one blog (the user owns the blog)
Blogs can have multiple posts.
Groups can have only one blog (but no particular user owns the blog, it is assumed the group owner created the blog thus userid is only an attribute of user blogs not group blogs so subtyping is needed)

[image]

When group_blog_post is deleted, the underlying blog_posts row should be deleted as well, is this best accomplished using a trigger?

Comment: What is the question: that the database is in 5NF or that a trigger should be used to delete blog_posts?

Comment: What's the difference between group blogs and blogs belonging to multiple people? Your design seems overly complicated...

Comment: I wanted to check whether this is valid 5NF design. Group blogs belongs to a group (no particular user owns/created it). User blogs is created by a user. Thus, userid is an attribute of user_blogs but not group_blogs. So blogs become the supertype and group_blogs, user_blogs become subtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table to be in 5NF, it must first be in 4NF. To be in 4NF, it must first be in 3NF. And so on, down to 1NF.

Loosely speaking, the lower normal forms have to do with dependencies between candidate keys and non-prime attributes.  But the only non-prime attributes we can see are "title" and "is_private". So there's really no way to tell.

To take one table as an example, "group_users" is in 5NF if it has no other columns.

**Later**

If you extend the table group_users like this

```
create table group_users (
  group_id integer not null references groups (group_id),
  user_id integer not null refrences users (user_id),
  user_type_id integer not null references user_types (user_type_id),
  primary key (group_id, user_id)
);
```

then you're still in 5NF. The column "user_type_id" isn't dependent only on user_id--if it were, you wouldn't be in 2NF. But the user_type_id isn't an attribute of the user alone; it's an attribute of the user *in this particular group*. No partial key dependencies; no transitive dependencies; no independent, multi-valued facts; no join dependencies; so it's in 5NF.

That structure allows only one user_type_id per user per group. If you think users should have multiple user types in each group, then this

```
create table group_users (
  group_id integer not null references groups (group_id),
  user_id integer not null refrences users (user_id),
  user_type_id integer not null references user_types (user_type_id),
  primary key (group_id, user_id, user_type_id)
);
```

is *also* in 5NF.  No partial key dependencies; no transitive dependencies; no independent, multi-valued facts; no join dependencies; so it's in 5NF.

Comment: Say group users had another column that stated the user type (admin, user, moderator etc). So it wouldn't be in 5nf because that user type wouldn't be part of the key (groupid, userid)? Then where does the user type attribute go???